# Old Anime About Girl Who Is A Puppet And Has Green Hair

Tags: story-identification, anime

The first episode starts off with the main protagonist who finds a girl with long green hair in his bathtub. She makes him pancakes and then he basically goes to school to try and figure out how this green haired girl got into his house. She can use kind of wind powers to blow people away? (From memory, she can also talk to trees because she's made out of wood.)

Later on, it is found that the male protagonist cast a spell by accident (chocolate might've been involved), because the male protagonist messed up his teacher's spell circle.

It is set in a kind of future like city. There was a couple as well. The guy was a baseball player and his girlfriend was a blonde girl with a high pony tail.

Later on I think a blonde guy is introduced and he's meant to marry/kidnap/capture the green haired girl.

There was also an episode where a mosquito uses special bath salts, advertised to make girls' skin more smooth and beautiful, but he's actually just trying to steal their blood.

I found this anime around early/mid 2000s and it was on youtube. I have been thinking about it for ages and I can't find anything about it. Please send help.

There was also a romance between the green haired puppet girl and the male protagonist.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [Trouble Chocolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trouble_Chocolate). The protagonist is named Cacao and the girl he finds sleeping next to him is named Hinano.

> Later on, it is found that the male protagonist cast a spell by accident (chocolate might've been involved), because the male protagonist messed up his teacher's spell circle.

Hinano was summoned by a magical accident caused by Cacao eating some 200 year old magical chocolate. So chocolate being involved is a good match - the title also refers to chocolate, and some of the characters have chocolate themed names: Cacao himself, his rival Truffle, and Professor Ganache who teaches magic at the school "Micro Grand Academy" where most of the action takes place.

> It is set in a kind of future like city.

The buildings of Micro Grand Academy have a futuristic design.

> There was a couple as well. The guy was a baseball player and his girlfriend was a blonde girl with a high pony tail.

The couple were named Murakata and Deborah - they were also the leader and second in command of the school security force "SMAT".

> Later on I think a blonde guy is introduced and he's meant to marry/kidnap/capture the green haired girl.

> There was also a romance between the green haired puppet girl and the male protagonist.

Both the protagonist Cacao, and his rival Truffle - the heir of the city's chocolate conglomerate - have feelings for Hinano.

Wikipedia has a brief plot description of the series as a whole:

> Cacao woke up to find a girl sleeping next to him. Unable to remember what had happened on his own and didn't get enough needed answers from Hinano, he went to school to ask his friends what had happened. He finally got the explanation of events from Professor Ghana in term Cacao joined his wizardry class.

Comment: @Valorum It's been a long time since I saw it, but I think most of the episode details fit. The only one I don't remember is the mosquito / bath salts / blood stealing episode. Atlhough blood stealing could refer to another character Professor Papaya - a vampire.

Comment: Much improved. A great answer.